# A way to stack a column on mobile

Tags: css, bulma

I tried using `is-flex-direction-row-reverse` on the columns class to enable it to reverse, which it did reverse on desktop but it doesn't take effect on mobile. The aim is on mobile not desktop.

The main effect it should take should be on mobile and not desktop. Please how do I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sadly your question does not meet the community guidelines. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and make it a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi, and welcome. Please share your code so far. Also, a picture would generally help.